# Google keep reminder sound/alarm

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-keep

Is it possible to add an actual alarm to a reminder in Google keep? Currently it just shows a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Google Keep will only show a notification for a reminder. You might try [MegaSound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.stefma.soundcontroll) to set an alarm sound for the Keep notifications.

Comment: MegaSound app works only for devices running Android 4.3 or Higher and it seems that OP has Android-4.1 Jelly bean device (since 4.1Jelly bean tag was used while posting)

Comment: @AADTechnical Not only that, it can't be upgraded, support for my device has ended.